# how to check if kendo grid datasource is empty

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In kendo grid how can I check if grid is empty or not? The following gives me this  error:

> unable to find resource of null reference

```
 $("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource().length>0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to check the number of items in the grid you can use the following:

```
$("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Product").data('kendoGrid').items().length
```

Hope this helps.